# while processing a many to many field my views.py is giving me error

Tags: django, django-forms

i have pasted my code along with stack trace at .. https://gist.github.com/2199510

my models.py

```
class Roles(models.Model):
    role = models.CharField(max_length=32)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.role

class Player(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    #name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team)
    role = models.ManyToManyField(Roles)
    preffered_position = models.IntegerField(max_length=3,choices=zip(range(1,12),range(1,12)) , default=1)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    #career statistics
    best_batting = models.IntegerField(max_length=6, default=0)
    best_bowling = models.CharField(max_length=6, default=0)


    #total batting statistics
    score = models.IntegerField(max_length=6, default=0)
    balls = models.IntegerField(max_length=6, default=0)

    #total bowling statistics
    overs = models.IntegerField(max_length=6, default=0)
    wickets = models.IntegerField(max_length=6, default=0)

    #total fielding statistics
    catches = models.IntegerField(max_length=6, default=0)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s %s" % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
```

my forms.py

```
class PlayerForm(forms.Form):
    first_name = forms.CharField()
    last_name = forms.CharField()
    role = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        Roles.objects.all(),
        widget=CheckboxSelectMultiple
    )
```

my views.py

```
def add_player(request, team_id):
    template = get_template('cricket/addplayer.html')
    loggedinuser = request.user
    userteam = Team.objects.get(owner=loggedinuser)
    currentteam = Team.objects.get(id=team_id)
    #now on to permissions .. if userteam = currentteam, the display form, otherwise display error "Permission denied"
    if userteam == currentteam:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = PlayerForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                Player.objects.create(
                    first_name = form.cleaned_data['first_name'],
                    last_name = form.cleaned_data['last_name'],
                    team = Team.objects.get(id=team_id),
                    role = form.cleaned_data['role'],
                )

                return HttpResponseRedirect('/team/%s/' % team_id)
        else:
            form = PlayerForm

        page_vars = Context({
            'form': form,
            'loggedinuser': loggedinuser,
            'team': userteam,
            })

        crsfcontext = RequestContext(request, page_vars)

        output = template.render(crsfcontext)
        return HttpResponse(output)
    else:
        error = "Permission Denied: You cannot add player to " + str(currentteam.name)
        page_vars = Context({
            'loggedinuser': loggedinuser,
            'error': error,
        })

        crsfcontext = RequestContext(request, page_vars)

        output = template.render(crsfcontext)
        return HttpResponse(output)
```

if somebody could tell me where and what i am doing wrong, that would be of great help.

//yousuf

Answer (score 0):

As the error message states, you can't pass `role` (or any ManyToMany field) as a keyword in the model instantiation call. You need to instantiate and save your model first, then add one or more roles with `player.roles.add(my_role)`.

Comment: 'Player' instance needs to have a primary key value before a many-to-many relationship can be used. :(

Comment: Yes, which is why I said you need to instantiate *and save* your model first. Saving gives it a PK value.

Comment: that helped ... but new problem .. "int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'QuerySet'"

Comment: @mouse, you need to explicitly specify the keyword `queryset` in the function.  So `role = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Roles.objects.all(),widget=CheckboxSelectMultiple)`